# ggplot2: how to set bar width of a specific bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am using ggplot2 to plot a set of numerical values. Among the variables in the dataset, there are two variables that are not fully crossed. The two variables are Height (4 levels: high, tense mid, lax mid, low) and Backness (4 levels: "u/o/ɔ", "y/ø/œ", "i/e/ɛ", "a"). The first three levels of Height combine with all first three levels of Backness. But the last levels of Height and Backness do not combine with the other levels. Here is the dataset:

```
mydata <- structure(list(Vowel = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("i", "e", "ɛ", "y", "ø", "œ", "u", "o", "ɔ", "a"), class = "factor"), distance = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("kp", "kt", "pt"), class = "factor"), Language = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L,2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("French", "non-French"), class = "factor"), mean.dist = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,2, 2, 2), sd.dist = c(0.120615504010632, 0.118412385311871, 0.121089776083054,0.149894186723077, 0.110166165335677, 0.112299637986508, 0.12939908491593, 0.115632300556256, 0.1232208247066, 0.125522547778451, 0.113827845634038, 0.121622532807705, 0.104520174716336, 0.131041477127477, 0.1224839610439, 0.10573903647089, 0.123680869606973, 0.113250190933477, 0.124947205620186, 0.116567786191159, 0.116711788711068, 0.138375016263539, 0.113070353979588, 0.109816142316869, 0.123866497777528, 0.128030948746137, 0.117993379792773, 0.116683458325427, 0.109730767345153, 0.119279399582146, 0.112930388666133, 0.131538829985269, 0.113242022434118, 0.104718500032215, 0.120046958765089, 0.122703726831522, 0.132890891589065, 0.151465602666509, 0.111960868349181, 0.166536043706081, 0.127513073089371, 0.11256771231828, 0.121444207664181, 0.120177407513513, 0.121259920821102, 0.129021201733638, 0.113933865258814, 0.122710394065478,0.107994086824079, 0.122041679482675, 0.127232388195383, 0.106014219374484,0.125177224086912, 0.12457590962369, 0.147765885739041, 0.124409226413158, 0.112718016807198, 0.156949752351136, 0.114751218006903, 0.114895198849989), Backness = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L,3L,3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("i/e/E", "y/ø/œ", "u/o/O", "a"), class = "factor"), Height = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L),.Label = c("high", "tense mid", "lax mid", "low"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Vowel", "distance", "Language", "mean.dist", "sd.dist", "Backness", "Height"), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = "data.frame")
```

When I try to plot this dataset using the code below (with fill=Height), the bar width for the combination of Height="low" and Backness="a" is very large and ugly (I guess it is as wide as the sum of the three thin bars for the other levels of Backness).

```
ggplot(mydata, 
 aes(factor(Backness), mean.dist, fill=Height)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(0.9)) + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean.dist-sd.dist, ymax=mean.dist+sd.dist), width=.2, position=position_dodge(0.9)) + facet_wrap(~Language+distance) + theme_bw() + ylab("d") + xlab("Vowel") + theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
                                axis.title=element_text(size=14), 
                                strip.text=element_text(size=14), 
                                legend.text = element_text(size=12)) + scale_fill_grey( start = 0.4, end = 0.8)
```

[image]

How can I get this bar to be as thin as the thinner bars on the plot? Thanks for your help!

Comment: There's a `width` option in `geom_bar`. It is not suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upcoming release of `ggplot` has a new `preserve` argument to `position_dodge` that allows for the behavior you want

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(factor(Backness), mean.dist, fill = Height)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(0.9, 'single')) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean.dist-sd.dist, ymax=mean.dist+sd.dist), 
                width=.2, position=position_dodge(0.9, 'single')) + 
  facet_wrap(~Language+distance) + 
  theme_bw() + ylab("d") + xlab("Vowel") + 
  scale_fill_grey( start = 0.4, end = 0.8)
```

[image]

Comment: How can I get the upcoming release of ggplot2?

Comment: `library(devtools); install_github('tidyverse/ggplot2')`